# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

```
// Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('bozy-mymodal');
    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('bozy22-popup');
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("image-01");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
```

This code is there in my custom.js in my WordPress theme, and it handles the image Popup, but on the front page opr other pages when there is no such even to handle than other Jqueries or custom queries written in custom.js doesn't **execute** such as Popmenu etc. what is the solution?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '**onclick**' of null
    at custom.js:20
    at custom.js:44
```

That seems to be looking for an image called `body22-popup`, which doesn't exist on that page but does on the page where the slider works.

```
var img = document.getElementById('body22-popup');
```

a similar situation is here →
[i'm getting an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808639/im-getting-an-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-property-onclick-of-null)

Is there a way to execute that part of the code in custom.js where such image that could be popped up doesn't exist.

In Wordpress, the scripts are added like this →

```
wp_register_script( 'custom-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.1', true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js' );
```

Comment: check the image tag must have id `body22-popup`

Comment: after your line with `var img =` could you add `console.log(img.length)` and tell the output in the console window

Comment: Do a null check for img before executing the code?

Comment: @taplr, please explain in detail as I am a Novice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So make sure that `img` is not null before you try to assign the handler:

```
...
var img = document.getElementById('bozy22-popup');
if ( img ) 
{
    img.onclick = function(){
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = this.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks sir, Let me try this. i will upload you soon.

Comment: my. upload me where..? :)   -- it will work for you, the check for img first will not assign the click handler on pages when it doesn't exist, meaning your error goes away.

Comment: where I am testing and building wp theme.

Comment: this is how the console looks like now → https://www.screencast.com/t/3Of4GZeOFC (I can share the live link if troubleshooting like this is an issue)

Comment: It seems you have many more errors than the one in your initial question, it's very difficult to help without seeing a whole lot more of the code...

Comment: You have the same situation with the `span` you are assigning a `onclick` to, test for it first using the same method we did to check your `img` exists. (`if ( span ) {...` :))

Comment: I have put the whole code in the if condition is this a authentic practice? https://www.screencast.com/t/tG5iSNZTIQ

Comment: No! you are checking for `img` before you even assign it, you assign it _inside_ the if condition, that's not going to work.

Comment: I also put the span in if  `    if ( span ) {
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }
     }`  Now no error.